# opacity of figcaption is mysteriously changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to use jquery.caption (https://github.com/louisbros/jquery.caption). I want the caption to be in a black rectangle with white text. When I mouse over my images, some of them display the caption correctly, but others don't display it at all, and others display it very lightly and hard to see. As I mouse over the images, some that were displaying it stop displaying it. If I look at the HTML I can see that the opacity changes and that is why the caption are sometimes not visible. When I first bring up the page, most of the elements have opacity=1, but others will have a very small number like 0.00301952217705548. As I mouse around, elements that started with opacity=1 will change to a very small number.

Here is my code that creates the elements:

```
$image_div = $('<div />')
   .addClass('gImage-row')
   .appendTo($preview);
$image_div.append($('<a />')
   .addClass('no-highlight')
   .attr('href', "{{ IMAGE_DIR }}"+image.image.replace(/thumbnail/,'jpg'))
   .attr('rel', "superbox[image]")
   .append($('<img />')
   .addClass('gImage')
   .attr('alt', 'some text')
   .attr('src', "{{ IMAGE_DIR }}"+image.image)
   .attr('onerror', "noimage(event)")));
```

This is in a loop and it creates 30-40 images.

In my window.onload function I do this:

```
$('.gImage-row img').caption();
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.figure{
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.figcaption{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background-color: black;
    foreground-color: white;
    opacity:1.0;
}

a:hover.no-highlight {
    background: transparent;
}

.gImage-row {
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
}

.gImage {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.label {
    float: left;
}
```

I cannot figure out what is making the opacity change or how to fix this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured out what is going on here. The code in jquery.caption was doing this:

```
$(this).bind('mouseenter.caption mouseleave.caption', function(){
    $(this).data('caption').figcaption.stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

fadeToggle works by changing the opacity. Because I had so many images close together, when the user moused around there were a lot of mouseenter and mouseleave events, and each time one occurred it would call stop on the existing fadeToggle. This would leave the opacity at whatever it was at at the moment. I changed this to:

```
$(this).bind('mouseenter.caption mouseleave.caption', function(){
    if ($(this).data('caption').figcaption.css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).data('caption').figcaption.show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).data('caption').figcaption.hide();
    }
});
```

And now it's working perfectly.